# How do I add my Ubuntu computer to my Windows 7 network?

Tags: networking

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on a computer and accessed the wireless network on which I have  primary and secondary computers running on Windows 7.  I can see both computer icons on all computers except I cannot see the Ubuntu computer on the network.

How do I add it to the network?

Answer (score 0):

You have to right click the folder you want to share in Ubuntu and enable the sharing options. [See this tutorial for details](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-access-ubuntu-shared-folders-windows-7).

For example:

1. To share your Public Folder in Ubuntu, go to your home directory and
   right-click on the Public Folder, then select `Sharing Options`.
2. Next, click the box to share this folder and install the services
   when prompted to do so.
3. Then allow Guest access as well and set the permissions as you wish.
   Finally, click `Create Share`.
4. Restart your computer and users on both machines should be able to
   access the Public Folder with authentications.

Also see: http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/06/windows-7-vs-ubuntu-12-04enable-public-folder-sharing-without-passwords/